# How to compare two vectors in R

Tags: r

I want to compare two vectors but it is not working, kindly tell me how two vectors can be compared:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
y <- c(5,6,7,8)
if (x==y) print("same") else print("different")
```

Comment: Look at `?all.equal` or `?identical`

Answer (score 2):

Use `all` can work here.

```
> all(x==y)
[1] FALSE
> y1=c(5,6,7,8)
> all(y==y1)
[1] TRUE
```

**EDIT**
best is to use `isTRUE(all.equal(x,y))` to avoid recycling

recycling

```
> x=c(5,6,5,6)
> y=c(5,6)
> all(x==y)
[1] TRUE
```

better way

```
> isTRUE(all.equal(x,y))
[1] FALSE
> isTRUE(all.equal(y,y1))
[1] TRUE
> x=c(5,6,5,6)
> y=c(5,6)
>isTRUE(all.equal(x,y))
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to array comparison,  `all` and `any` are your friends. If you do not really mean geometric vector but array of values, `sort` should also be necessary:

```
> all(sort(x)==sort(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
y <- c(5,6,7,8)
if(identical(x,y)) print("identical") else print("not identical")
```